# How to make AWS Polly SynthesizeSpeech() asynchronous?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

According to [this AWS documentation for Polly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/API_SynthesizeSpeech.html), the asynchronous version of the function is no longer there. So now every time I use it in my game, the animation would stop for a while whenever Polly is called, because ***SynthesizeSpeech()*** is blocking.

Why has AWS removed the ***SynthesizeSpeechAsync()*** function? What is supposed to be the workaround?

Comment: why? unless you hit  a jackpot and find a polly worker, who knows

Comment: why not just use non async? if you have a long time to wait, try elevenlabs.